# how to fix reactjs syntax error: unexpected token?

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I have created a simple create-react-app and first it was running perfectly and once i add some codes with some modules(axios,react-router-dom etc..) i get the following error message. I'm new to react.js and have no idea of how this is happening. Any idea?
[image]

Comment: Can you write a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this error now. You should not import Link by this way:

```js
import Link from "react-router-dom/modules/Link";
```

This way is better:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```